# Couldn't find Friendship without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

First of all, I've searched stack overflow and google to find out the problem but unfortunately I wasn't able to fix the problem.

This problem occurred, right after I upgraded my rails 4.2 app to 5.0.

I have a friendship system in my app. I can send friendship request but I cannot cancel it. When I try, rails throws an error saying `Couldn't find Friendship without an ID`

```
  def self.breakup(user, friend)
    transaction do
      destroy(find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend))
      destroy(find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(friend, user))
    end
  end
```

[image]

Here is the Friendship model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
  # -- Associations ------------------------------------------------------------ #
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
  # -- Validation Logic -------------------------------------------------------- #
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :friend_id

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
  # -- Connection Logic -------------------------------------------------------- #
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

  # -- Create A Friendship Request --------------------------------------------- #
  def self.send_request(user, friend)
    unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user, friend)
      transaction do
        create(user: user, friend: friend, status: 'pending')
        create(user: friend, friend: user, status: 'requested')
      end
    end
  end

  # -- Accept Friendship Request ----------------------------------------------- #
  def self.accept_request(user, friend)
    transaction do
      accept_one_side(user, friend)
      accept_one_side(friend, user)
    end
  end

  # -- Decline Friendship Request, Disconnect or Cancel Pending Request -------- #
  def self.breakup(user, friend)
    transaction do
      destroy(find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend))
      destroy(find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(friend, user))
    end
  end

  # -- Return True If The Users Are (Possibly Pending) Friends ----------------- #
  def self.exists?(user, friend)
    not find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend).nil?
  end

  # -- Update The DB With One Side of An Accepted Friendship Request ----------- #
  private
  def self.accept_one_side(user, friend)
    request = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
    request.status = 'accepted'
    request.save!
  end
end
```

Here is the Friendship controller:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :setup_friends

  def connect
    Friendship.send_request(@user, @friend)
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end

  def accept
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.accept_request(@user, @friend)
    end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end

  def cancel
    if @user.pending_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
    end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end

  def decline
    if @user.requested_friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
    end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end

  def disconnect
    if @user.friends.include?(@friend)
      Friendship.breakup(@user, @friend)
    end
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end

  private
  def setup_friends
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @friend = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

When I command+click on `find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)`, RubyMine takes me to here:

```
def method_missing(name, *arguments, &block)
  match = Method.match(self, name)

  if match && match.valid?
    match.define
    send(name, *arguments, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you got test coverage for this app?

Comment: No, I haven't. This app is still in development and I wanted switch to 5.0 before the release.

Comment: Sounds like it could do with some tests. You have a github repo for it? I could take a look and maybe do a PR for it.